Didn't find class "byte"
When I was hooking a function, the second parameter of the function was a byte array, so I wrote the following code to hook the function：
    function Hook() {
        let xxx= Java.use("xxxx");
        xxx["$init"].overload('java.lang.String','[B', 'java.lang.String', 'java.util.Map',             'boolean').implementation = function (str, bArr, str2, map, z) {
        this["$init"](str, bArr, str2, map, z);
    };

}
But frida reported an error, as follows：
enter image description here
I changed the overload to what the arrow points to and continued running frida, but the app crashed.
Look at the log, as shown below
enter image description here
Please tell me, what causes this? What should I do?
The reason for the error is that the byte class was not found, but byte is a basic data type. I guess this is a Frida bug? My frida version is 16.5.6

Please do not post text error messages as screenshot, instead copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code. What Android version is installed on the phone you use for running the app?
